# How many decompositions $k=\jmath_1+\ldots+\jmath_k$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k$ be a non-negative integer. How many decompositions of $k$ as a sum $\jmath_1+\ldots+\jmath_k$ of non-negative integers are there? I didn't mistype $\jmath_k$.

Each permutation of the $\jmath_i$'s in $\jmath_1+\ldots+\jmath_k$ must be taken into accoun. For example, if $k=4$ then I want to count all the possible forms $4=3+1+0+0$, $4=3+0+1+0$, $4=3+0+0+1$, etc..

Thanks.

Comment: If you allow zero summands, a good name for these is *weak compositions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add $1$ to each of the $k$ terms, you get a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $2k$ into $k$ parts, and it is well-known that there are $\binom{2k-1}{k-1}$ of these; the argument given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions) is concise but quite clear.